# Creating graphs in a JS Web Extension

Tags: javascript, html

I need to to be able to create graphics concerning my data within a web extension I am creating (which is solely implemented in Firefox, presently).

Presently, it would seem that I will have to create graphs by hand using the HTML `<canvas>` tags.

Is there any way I could leverage outside libraries in my web extension, in lieu of writing it all by hand?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) library it is built on Canvas and you need only set required properties